Azure Cloud Shell not loading in Chrome but works in Edge
When i try to start Cloud Shell from the Portal in Chrome browser I get a grey area with no functionality.  When I try it in Edge I get a working Cloud Shell interface.  I have a storage account and vnet configured, everything works fine in Edge.
I am using the lastest version of Chrome and Win11 is fully patched.
This problem occured when I had a Cloud Shell instance running in Chrome and exitted out of VS Code on my secondary monitor while I had a AZ-104 lesson fullscreen on my primary.  The second monitor switched off (decided to stop receiving signal from the GPU) and primary started flickering.  I hard reset my machine to get things back up and running.  Ever since this Cloud Shell wont work.
I deleted my storage account where Cloud Shell img was stored and recreated in Edge via teh automatic process when you first run Cloud Shell.  This worked great for Edge but Chrome is still suffering.
I have tried clearing ALL browser data from Chrome and disabled ALL extensions but it stil wont display anything when I try to open Cloud Shell in Chrome.
Im happy to provide more info and screenshots if you need them but I would really appreciate any help you guys can offer becuase this has me stumped and is annoying me no end.
Thanks

Fixed!
I had to completely uninstall Chrome using Revo Uninstaller and removed EVERY single trace of Chrome, as the standard uninstaller still leaves traces behind in the registry and other places.

Please post your sol as an answer

Fixed! I had to completely uninstall Chrome using Revo Uninstaller and removed EVERY single trace of Chrome, as the standard uninstaller still leaves traces behind in the registry and other places
